# Montar un volumen local en un contenedor usando Dockerfile?

Tags: apache, docker

Estoy intentando hacer que un directorio local sea linkado dentro del contenedor, explico porque.

La idea es tener un container con el S.O corriendo pero que el proyecto web se encuentre alojado en una carpeta local. Se que utilizando el comando:

```
-v /path/on/host:/path/in/container
```

en el `Docker run` es posible. Pero mi intención y creo que lo más óptimo sería poder montar el directorio local dentro del `Dockerfile`, cuando se hace el "build", para que así el resto de personas del equipo no tenga lugar a errores.

Gracias.

Comment: Tu puedes usar `VOLUME "PATH_VOLUME", pero recuerda si es para desarrollo y quieres algo como un `share directory` no es posible hacerlo en tu `DOCKER FILE`, para ello se usa el comando que mencionas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El parámetro "-v" es para montarlo desde la terminal, para usar volúmenes en un dockerfile puedes seguir la documentación [aquí](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/volume), también tienes varias opciones para administrar [volúmenes nombrados y creados específicamente](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/)